# Error: reassigning content to a different user is not supported on multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

Objective:There's a need to remove a user from the multisite. Before doing so, user's content needs to be "transferred to another user" in a subdomain setting/specific site that's not the parent.

This wp-cli command is used:
wp user delete --network 898 --reassign=911

When it is used, an error message is gotten is return:
Error: reassigning content to a different user is not supported on multisite.

So, Instead used this to get objective done:

echo reassigntest.xx.xx.xxx.edu | xargs -I % wp user delete userName --reassign=911 --url=%

This deletes user from reassigntest.xx.xx.xxx.edu on the multisite, but does not do the reassignment.

Is there any syntax issue with either of the two commands used above?
If not, then got alternative to get objective accomplished?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems no matter what, if you try to use [--reassign] along with [--network], you will get the Error "Reassigning content to a different user is not supported on multisite."

However, for the second part. To remove a user from one site and reassign the posts, you can use the following:

```
wp user delete userName --url=https://www.siteURL.com/ --reassign=911
```

**Note:** For the [--reassign] you **MUST** use the user-id (numeric value) here, otherwise it will not reassign the posts. If you aren't sure of the ID for the user you want, you can find it with:

```
wp user list
```

After you reassign the posts for each single site, you can safely remove the user from the network.

```
wp user delete userName --network --yes
```

The [--yes] Option is to answer yes to all prompts. In this case it would say;

"--reassign parameter not passed. All associated posts will be deleted".

Well... we wanted to reassign the posts network-wide. It wasn't "supported". Pretty annoying, but as long as you reassigned all the posts before running the --network delete, you should be fine to answer "yes".